# sudo command is unsucessful when invoked from file manager

Tags: fedora, sudo

I'm trying to run the following script on an install of Fedora 20.

```
#!/bin/bash
password={password}
echo "$password" | sudo -Sk /bin/bash -c '[[ $EUID -eq 0 ]]'
[[ $? -ne 0 ]] && zenity --error --text failed. || zenity --error --text success.
```

When trying to run from a terminal emulator, it reports success, but when double clicking the script from a file manager (Thunar in this case), it reports failure.

On some other distros (e.g. Debian Wheezy), I get a consistent behaviour.

Why would that be the case and what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to mention that "failure is reported" without quoting the error message...

Comment: Hopefully the downvoter would explain why...

Comment: @HaukeLaging: As in: `zenity --error --text failed.` is executed.

Comment: Is the stdout and stderr from the script available anywhere? Perhaps you could redirect the output of the sudo so you can see what actually happened?

Comment: Putting your password in a script is a bad idea. Instead, let the user enter the password, or configure sudo to run the command without a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the /etc/sudoers file (accessible with visudo), look for `requiretty`. You can turn this off for the program with:

```
Defaults!/path/to/program !requiretty
```

In your case - you are using bash, so this path would be whatever you get from `which bash`.

Answer (score 1):

You should verify that sudo doesn't require tty in the `/etc/sudoers` file  (`requiretty` should not be set).